# Scikit learn gaussian process returns constant variance for 2 samples

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using scikit learn's gaussian process (GP) tools for Bayesian Optimization. I have noticed a weird trend that keeps influencing my results. When I enter the following code for fitting the GP to one data point

```
import numpy as np
import sklearn.gaussian_process as gp

#domain
x = np.linspace(-3,3,10).reshape(-1,1)

#create gaussian process
kernel = gp.kernels.Matern()
model = gp.GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel,
                                    alpha=1e-5,
                                    n_restarts_optimizer=10,
                                    normalize_y=True)
#fit to first data point
model.fit(np.array([[0.72]]), np.array([[-0.665]]))
#precict mean, standard deviaion over domain
mu, std = model.predict(x, return_std=True)

print std
```

I get a good looking standard deviation that decreases near the sampled point of x=0.72:

> [0.99992986 0.99949578 0.99661166 0.97932637 0.89018143 0.51921629
>    0.40500728 0.8588613  0.97270708 0.99544088]

However, I then implement the same GP for a second data point as follows:

```
#fit to first and second data point
model.fit(np.array([[0.72],[-2.99]]), np.array([[-0.665],[0.2168]]))
#precict mean, standard deviaion over domain
mu, std = model.predict(x, return_std=True)

print std
```

and receive a weird looking vector that only goes below 1 at the first point

[0.7028552 1.        1.        1.        1.        1.        1.
 1.        1.        1.       ]

This certainly cannot be true, as we still have some confidence in the original point. when I include a third point, the standard deviation again looks normal, however, this oddity in the second point is causing problems with my optimization routine, and I do not understand why it is occuring.